# Rescanning the configuration file in groovy

Tags: groovy, configuration-files

I need to implement a configuration file, which should be rescanned periodically or after an edit, what should I do?

I tried

```
config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(Config);
```

its not working when `Config.groovy` changes dynamically.

Example (from comment below)

#### MyConfig.groovy

```
class MyConfig {
  public static ConfigObject config
  public static void run() {
    config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(Config)
  }
  public static void printconfig() {
    println config.options.video.enable
  }
}

MyConfig.run()
for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
  Thread.sleep(3000)
  MyConfig.printconfig()
}
```

#### Config.groovy

```
options { video { enable = false } }
```

Comment: Do you have some example code showing it not working?  Also, is this `grails`?

Comment: class MyConfig {
    public static  ConfigObject config ;
    public static void run(){
       config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(Config);

    }
    public static void printconfig(){
        println config.options.animals.enableFish
        println config.options.products.enableFishFood
    }

}

Comment: Added that to your question...  Where do you get `Config` from in the call `new ConfigSlurper().parse(Config)` from inside `run`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to parse the config file once, then never re-parse it...

What you could do is store the last modified date of the file, and call `run()` again from `printConfig` if it detects the file has been modified...

Also, I assume you have a copy/paste error...  Shouldn't:

```
config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(Config)
```

be:

```
config = new ConfigSlurper().parse( MyConfig.class.getResource( 'Config.groovy' ) )
```

Or something?

Comment: config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(Config)

it did work.
I did think about using lastmodified time of a file to reparse it,
but I thought there should be some 'groovy' way to do it.

Comment: Config is a class that got created... because of Config.groovy

Comment: @ticktock Ahhh right...  But if it's built at compile time, how are you intending to dynamically update it?

Comment: I don't want to parse the file every time before I access a configuration variable, so am looking if there is any groovy way to periodically rescan the modified config file...

Comment: @ticktock Why not simply check the lastModified date of the file when you try and access the ConfigObject, and re-parse it if it is different to last time it was parsed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9648/discussion-between-ticktock-and-tim-yates)